# Can I upgrade Python version upgrade from 2.7.12 to 2.7.14 on my windows system

Tags: python

Currently I am using python 2.7.12 on my windows system. I want to upgrade my python version from 2.7.12 to 2.7.14. 
Do I need to run the 2.7.14 msi and during installation I have to provide the same path where 2.7.12 is installed (In my system , the installation directory is C:\Python27 ?

Comment: If you run the MSI, it will automatically detect the current install and should upgrade it.

Comment: If you are using Anaconda, simply use `conda upgrade python`